# Handling newline character while executing Bigquery cmd via Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have sql query in a string variable that I am executing via Python. The problem I am facing is that I can't pass '\n' in the string variable. When using CHR(13) || CHR(10) I get following error -

Argument 2 to STRING_AGG must be a literal or query parameter

Query -

```
sql_stmt="""
    SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || DATA_TYPE || ',' , CHR(13)) AS COLUMN_LIST
    FROM  `prj_name.dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
"""
```

I am then using bigquery to execute the above statement using the client.query(sql_stmt) command. If I pass '\n' as command query is failing as string is getting split into two parts and failing.

Can someone tell me how I can handle this situation?

Comment: **'\\n'** doesn't work ?

Comment: maybe try with `sql_stmt=r"""..."""` (note the `r`) and using `\n` instead of `CHR(13)`

Comment: Placing r worked. Thank you @99_m4n. Jaytiger - this was just one part of SQL where I had to replace \n. When I have applied this at multiple places I was not getting the expected results.

Comment: I wrote the previous comment as answer to mark the question as answered. Glad it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `sql_stmt=r"""..."""` (note the `r`) and using `\n` instead of `CHR(13)`

Answer (score 0):

As @Jaytiger mentined you can use `'\\n'` instead of `CHR(13)`.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project="prj_name")

query = """
SELECT  STRING_AGG(COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || DATA_TYPE || ',' , '\\n') AS COLUMN_LIST
FROM  `prj_name.dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
"""

job = client.query(query)
res = job.result()
for r in res:
    print(r.COLUMN_LIST)
```

Comment: Thanks Max. Putting in double slash n across multiple places was giving me unexpected results. I was able to get it to work using r in the front of the string as suggested by 99_m4n.